# Time Picker for Minutes and Seconds Only

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need a timePicker for minutes and seconds and I would like to avoid having to make a custom UIpickerView. Is there a quick way to do this? I saw some tutorials for (hours/minutes/seconds) but I only need 2 columns: Minutes and Seconds.

Comment: You need to make custom time picker for full fill your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to create your own UIPickerView instance or subclass and configure it with Minutes and Seconds easily enough.

```
let arrMins = [0...60]
var arrSec = [0...60] 

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
  return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
switch component {
    case 1: return arrMins.count
    case 2: return arrSec.count
}
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
 switch component {
    case 1: return "\(arrMins[row]) Mins"
    case 2: return "\(arrSec[row]) Sec"
    }
}
```